# Touch anywhere on screen EXCEPT GUI button Android Unity

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine

I m developing an android game, i have an orthographic camera that i can move left right , up and down with touch , i created a gui button. I export the apk to device when i touch anywhere i can move the camera, but when i touch the gui button that i created, the camera also move. I want when i click on the button .the camera stop moving and when i touch anywhere to the screen the camera move.Or is there a possibility to move the camera when  i touch the screen and  i double click on the button .I created a boolean [ButtonPressed]but it's not working the camera move when i also click on GUI Button Here is my code:

```
Touch touch;
public Vector2 startPos;
Vector2 endPos;
public bool fingerHold = false;
public bool ButtonPressed = false;


void Update()
{
if(!ButtonPressed)
{
  if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
       touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
       if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
       {
          startPos = touch.position;
          fingerHold = true;
       }
       else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
       {
          endPos = touch.position;
       }
       else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
       {
          fingerHold = false;
        }
    }
        if (fingerHold)
        {

            float deltaX = endPos.x - startPos.x;
            float deltaY = endPos.y - startPos.y;
            bool horizontal = false;

            if (Mathf.Abs(deltaX) > Mathf.Abs(deltaY))
                horizontal = true;

            if (horizontal)
            {
                if (deltaX < 0 )
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 20);
                else if (deltaX > 0)
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 20);
            }
            else
            {
                if (deltaY < 0)
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 20);
                else if (deltaY > 0)
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20);
            }
        }
      }
    }
void OnGUI()
{
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 158, 54), "Click Button"))
        {
           ButtonPressed = true; 
           Print("Button Clicked");
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your touch is inside buttons bounds ,

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
   startPos = touch.position;

   // if we touch inside the buttons bounds get out of here!
   if(startPos.x < 168 && startPos.y < 64) return;

   fingerHold = true;
}
```